# Creating a calculated field using ant forms

Tags: reactjs, antd

How do I create a field who gets its value from combining two other fields using ant forms?

An example, I have a `First Name` field and a `Last Name` field.

I want `Full Name` field to be the combination of First Name and Last Name. When either first or last name is updated, `Full Name` field should get updated as well.

I tried setting `dependencies` on the `Full Name` field but I'm not certain how to update the Full Name value and listen for changes.

According [to the docs](https://ant.design/components/form/#dependencies):

> If a field has the dependencies prop, this field will automatically
> trigger updates and validations

How do listen to these updates that are automatically triggered?

##### Update

[This is my attempt](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fwz7mm-j5u9ki?file=index.js):

```
const TestI = ({value, onChange}) => {
  console.log("L19 value:", value);
  console.log("L20 onChange", onChange);
  return <Input value={value} onChange={onChange} />;
}

const RegistrationForm = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  const onFinish = values => {
    console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
  };

  return (
    <Form form={form} name="register" onFinish={onFinish} scrollToFirstError>
      <Form.Item name="FirstName" label="First Name">
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item name="LastName" label="Last Name">
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item
        dependencies={['FirstName', 'LastName']}
        name="FullName"
        label="Full Name"
        rules={[
          () => {
            return {
              validator(_, value) {
                console.log('validating l40...value', value);
                return Promise.resolve();
              }
            };
          }
        ]}
      >
        <TestI />
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

The problem seems to be that `Full Name` only gets updated when it's "dirty" (value is not initial value) and even then only validation runs when one of its dependencies changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. But below solution was using the [antd form hooks](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-control-hooks) (since you also used it)

```
const [form] = Form.useForm();

const onValuesChange = (changedValues, allValues) => {
    const fieldName = Object.keys(changedValues)[0];
    if (fieldName === "FirstName" || fieldName === "LastName") {
        const FirstName =
            changedValues["FirstName"] || allValues["FirstName"] || "";
        const LastName =
            changedValues["LastName"] || allValues["LastName"] || "";

        form.setFieldsValue({ FullName: `${FirstName} ${LastName}` });
    }
};

const onFinish = values => {
    console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
};

<Form
    form={form}
    name="register"
    onFinish={onFinish}
    scrollToFirstError
    onValuesChange={onValuesChange}
>
    <Form.Item name="FirstName" label="First Name">
        <Input />
    </Form.Item>
    <Form.Item name="LastName" label="Last Name">
        <Input />
    </Form.Item>
    <Form.Item name="FullName" label="Full Name">
        <Input />
    </Form.Item>
</Form>
```

The logic all happened on **onValuesChange** callback

See example here:

[image: Edit]